# Set Panel Fit display mode

Tags: c++, windows, intel, resolution

After switching to Windows 10, I've noticed that when selecting a lower than normal screen resolution, the panel fit mode will default to "Maintain Aspect Ratio" meaning black bars appear. Every single time I do this, I have to manually set the panel fit mode to "Scale Full Screen".

I do this very frequently so I'd like to automate the process. I can adjust the resolution fine but cannot fine any API whatsoever to adjust the panel fit. Using a registry monitor, I've found that the setting changes some DWM keys. I'm assuming that some function will need to be called programmatically afterwards to apply the changes.

I've found nothing in the DWM API on MSDN, but I could've missed something.

What am I looking for?